# inspect functionality gets lost during Cython

Tags: python, cython, inspect

Inside some functions I'm using `inspect` package to get the name of the outer calling functions, whatever that might.
After the code Cython-ized, it generates this error:

```
ValueError: call stack is not deep enough
ERROR   : call stack is not deep enough
```

An example of how `inspect` is used(nothing fancy):

```
def some_func(**kwargs):
   <code>
   inspect.stack()[0][3]
   <more code>
```

Anyone bumped into this issue?
I searched the web looking for similar problems but no luck today.
Hopefully, I can get some help from here!

PS: Feel free to edit the question if you think that the Title is not suggestive enough!

Comment: Be aware that ``inspect`` often looks at the *interpreter* state. Using it for un-interpeted code or partially-interpreted code may-or-may-not produce the desired results.

Comment: Hm! How do you get it working, in that case?

Comment: You don't. It absolutely won't work with Cython.

Comment: This is the relevant documentation: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/limitations.html#stack-frames. I suspect it might be possible to work around it if the outer calling function is in Python (maybe putting inspect in `exec` or similar) but if the outer calling function is in Cython then there's nothing to be done.